# manipulate python lists into strings

Tags: python

I asked a question about how to take `A_board=[['0', '0'],['1', '1']]`. And I want to take this nested list apart and get a `result`, which if I call `print result`, it would display: `< 0 0 > < 1 1 >.`

I was told to use `' '.join('< {} {} >'.format(*items) for items in A_board)`, but this only works for two tuples, it is not flexible. What if I have a `[[0],[0],[0]]` and want to make it into `< 0 > < 0 > < 0 >` ? Right now I have to type in an extra `{}` everytime the `len(A_board)` increases.

ex. if `A_board` length is 2, then there will be two `{}`'s

if `A_board` length is 3, then there will be three `{}`'s

what is a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could just do another join:

```
' '.join('< {} >'.format(' '.join(items)) for items in A_board)
```

which will work for any length of `items`.

Comment: I think `.join(map(str, items))` is needed as they're `ints` but yup :)